# Post tweet from client's account using Java

Tags: java, twitter, desktop-application

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4413688/1291122) SO answer and other google search results, it seems that twitter has stopped supporting username and password based authentication to post updates. However to my surprise, when I downloaded [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tweet-fire/) app, it amazed me as it simply allows me to send tweets using my username and password only, requiring no consumer key and consumer secrets. So how is that possible?

All the tutorial I went through after googling suggested that I need to register my app and use the access token for posting. This also requires entering some PIN if I use it in my app. What I want is that my app must allow the **client** to enter only username and password to post tweets. So how should I do that in java?

I would even welcome a solution which utilizes the above app only to post tweets.(e.g. using Runtime.getRuntime())

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351794/how-to-make-a-user-tweet-into-his-her-twitter-account-from-java-web-application) unanswered SO question. This is similar to what I want to do. Only that I want to do it using desktop application.